# Rails sessions fails first time and passes on reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, actioncontroller

On login, and logout I end up getting this error when trying the first time. However, after refreshing it goes through.

"The change you wanted was rejected.
Maybe you tried to change something you didn't have access to.
If you are the application owner check the logs for more information."

In my logs I get an ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken error so it has to be something with my sessions however I can't find anything to add.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rails helpers to create the form?

If not, you might need to add a CSRF token field. Using rail's form helper does it automatically for you.

**Update:**

Also check if your application controller has `protect_from_forgery`

Comment: Are you referring to the signin form? If so, it is currently being created using form_for(:session, :url sessions_path)

Comment: Yes, the sign in form. Does it have a token field if you view source in the browser?

Comment: Yep, <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="hash" />. Also, <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" /> in the header.

Comment: Just updated the answer -- check if ```protect_from_forgery``` is there in the application controller.

Comment: Also, protect_from_forgery with: :exception in app controller.

Comment: It's most definitely an issue with the CSRF token somewhere. Your issue seems similar to this one: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/11/17/i-saw-an-extremely-subtle-bug-today-and-i-just-have-to-tell-someone/